# How do I find Shadowmere again if I lose her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I dismounted Shadowmere during a fight in the woods and became separated from her.  Now I can't find her.  Is there any way to find her without wandering aimlessly through the woods?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a tricky one as it's possible to actually bug out Shadowmere and have her disappear from the game completely.

A couple of different steps to try:

- Fast Travel to a known location, like a stables. She may appear with you.
- Travel to Shadowmere's "home" at Fort Faragut.
- Enter a town and leave again, have a look in the stables. She may be stabled there.

As I said, it is possible to completely lose Shadowmere. If your on PC there is a console command that will spawn a new instance of her next to you, but I don't know it off the top of my head.

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 7):

Fast-Travel back to Fort Farragut, and walk right up to the main doors to go in and Shadowmere will be standing there waiting for you.
Shadowmere should always be waiting for you there if you get separated.

Comment: That was it.  Accept to Alastair, though, for being first with other options as well. +1 though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a console command to spawn her right in front of you!

If you're using the PC version press <kbd>~</kbd> to open up the console command and then enter the following directive:

```
player.PlaceAtMe 00032BF4 1
```

This will spawn 1 Shadowmere right in front of you. You can also spawn any other horse you want, just look up the console codes on the Fandom site / UESP / ESP.

Answer (score 0):

Shadowmere respawns allways into Ft.Faragut, but ONLY when she´s UNARMORED. If you got *HorseArmor* addon - than you need seek for shadowmere´s RefID ...  that may be possibly 0x002122  So - open console, type: player.moveto 0x002122 enter.  Oh, that *x* there means code for refID of yer armrd shadmre...  If yer horsie is *naked* - just open console and type: player.moveto 00032BF5 enter ... 
Even may try to type: enable 00032bf5 enter. That gives to you new shadowmere, yea can than ride her to impSity and buy at stableork one armor again ...  etc...